# PyQt Threading: GUI interaction Crashes Program

Tags: python, multithreading, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I am designing a program to edit DICOMs. Specifically, I am having issues appropriately interacting with my PyQt UI.

I want to be able to click on a "pause" and on a "stop" button to either pause or stop my editing function. My editing function takes a significant amount of time to process / loop through. Depending on the number of files that it is editing, it can take anywhere from 30 seconds to over an hour. Because of this, I decided to throw my editing function into its own thread using the native threading capabilities of Qt. I was able to get the thread working ie: from my MainWindow class I can click a button that initializes my editing class (class edit(QThread), however interacting with the GUI still crashes the program and I'm not sure why! Below I have added a sample of the general code structure / set up that I am using.

```
class anonymizeThread(QThread):
    def __init__(self):
        QThread.__init__(self)


    def __del__(self):
        self.wait()

    #def sendAnon(self, progress_val):
     #   self.completed = 0
      #  return self.completed


    def run(self):
            # while self.completed < 100:
            #     self.completed += 0.00001
            #     self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL('PROGRESS'), self.completed)
            # ANONYMIZE FUNCTION!
            i = 0
            #flag = self.stop_flag
            while i < 10000000: # and self.stop_flag is not 1:
                print(i)
                i+=1
            print('i didnt enter the loop')


class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        # connect the buttons
        self.worker = anonymizeThread()
        self.anonbtn.clicked.connect(self.anonymize)
        self.open_directory.clicked.connect(self.open_dir)
        self.pause.clicked.connect(self.paused)
        self.stopbtn.clicked.connect(self.stopped)

        # block button signals to start
        self.pause.blockSignals(True)
        self.stopbtn.blockSignals(True)

        self.dir_name = None
        self.pause_flag = None
        self.stop_flag = None
        self.anon_flag = None

        # This is how we quit from the main menu "File" option
        extractAction = self.actionQuit_Ctrl_Q
        extractAction.setShortcut("Ctrl+Q")
        extractAction.setStatusTip('Leave The App')
        extractAction.triggered.connect(self.close_application)



    def updateProgressBar(self,val):
        self.progressBar.setValue(val)
    def close_application(self):
        choice = QMessageBox.question(self, 'Just had to check...', "Are you sure you want to exit?", QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No)
        if choice == QMessageBox.Yes:
            sys.exit()
        else:
            pass

    def anonymize(self):
        self.pause.blockSignals(False)
        self.stopbtn.blockSignals(False)
        self.worker.start()
        # check if directory chosen
        # self.progressBar.setMaximum(len(dcm)
        # start our anon thread!


    def paused(self):
        #only if running
        if self.pause_flag is 0:
            self.pause_flag = 1
            self.pause.setText('Start')
        elif self.pause_flag is 1:
            self.pause_flag = 0
            self.pause.setText('Pause')
        else:
            pass

    def stopped(self): # need a self.stop() for anonThread

        choice = QMessageBox.question(self,'Stop', "Are you sure you want to stop? You will not be able to pick up exactly where you left off.",
                              QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No)
        if choice == QMessageBox.Yes:
            self.stop_flag = 1
            #self.stopbtn.blockSignals(True)
            #self.paused.blockSignals(True)
        else:
            pass


    def open_dir(self):
        self.dir_name = str(QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, "Select Directory"))
        if len(self.dir_name) is not 0:
            self.anon_flag = 0




def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = MainWindow()
    main_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Why do you use blockSignals?, also please share a reproducible code since the stop_flag attribute does not exist in the editThread class

Comment: Surely it should be: `self.worker.stop_flag = 1`? And obviously you need to put `self.stop_flag = 0` in `editThread.__init__`.

Comment: Where's the stack trace?

Comment: I wanted to block the ability to hit the stop button as well as the pause button before the edit thread was running. My thought was that calling self.stop_flag = 1 under the MainWindow class and under the def stopped(self) function would suffice for changing the value of stop_flag to 1

I did accidentally omit a line of code when I copied and pasted: self.stop_flag = 0 in the __init__ of MainWindow. I have changed it in the above question

Comment: @eyllanesc I am new to pyqt/qt in general. I thought that class thread would inherit "self" from the MainWindow?

Comment: No, you are creating a new thread, the main thread is the GUI, and only secondary threads can be created.

Comment: Which button would launch the editThread thread?

Comment: What is the start, stop and pause button?

Comment: I had removed those in order to try and simplify the problem (and focus just on the stop button). Sorry about that. I have edited the original post to include everything but I have no fully integrated / worked on the pause button functionality. Edit (anonymize in the pure copy paste of my code) calls the Qthread as self.worker.start()

How would I pass a variable ie: stop_flag from my mainwindow class to the QThread class in real time?

Comment: Would this be an appropriate time to use a global variable?

Comment: try with my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is advisable not to access the flags directly, it is better to do it through the functions to make use of it transparently, for this the same class should verify the tasks.

Also it is good to give a small delay so that the application can deal with the graphic part, another possible improvement is to avoid usat sys.exit, you could call the close method that closes the window.

In the following code I have implemented the stop and pause methods.

```
class anonymizeThread(QThread):
    def __init__(self):
        QThread.__init__(self)
        self.onRunning = True
        self.onStop = False


    def __del__(self):
        self.wait()

    def stop(self):
        self.onStop = True

    def pause(self):
        if self.isRunning():
            self.onRunning = not self.onRunning


    def run(self):
            i = 0
            #flag = self.stop_flag
            while i < 10000000:
                if self.onRunning: # and self.stop_flag is not 1:
                    print(i)
                    i+=1

                if self.onStop:
                    break
                QThread.msleep(10)
            print('i didnt enter the loop')


class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)


        # connect the buttons
        self.worker = anonymizeThread()
        self.anonbtn.clicked.connect(self.anonymize)
        self.pause.clicked.connect(self.paused)
        self.stopbtn.clicked.connect(self.stopped)

        # block button signals to start
        self.pause.blockSignals(True)
        self.stopbtn.blockSignals(True)

    def close_application(self):
        choice = QMessageBox.question(self, 'Just had to check...', "Are you sure you want to exit?", QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No)
        if choice == QMessageBox.Yes:
            self.close()

    def anonymize(self):
        self.pause.blockSignals(False)
        self.stopbtn.blockSignals(False)
        self.worker.start()


    def paused(self):
        self.worker.pause()

    def stopped(self): # need a self.stop() for anonThread

        choice = QMessageBox.question(self,'Stop', "Are you sure you want to stop? You will not be able to pick up exactly where you left off.",
                              QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No)
        if choice == QMessageBox.Yes:
            self.worker.stop()
```

Comment: Is the QThread.msleep() necessary? It technically would slow down that thread's operation. Without it, would there be a chance that a button click could still crash the program? Thanks for implementing the pause, it works perfectly.

I would upvote but apparently I need 15 reputation to do so :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @eyllansec and @ekhumoro..

In the above code, all instances of `self.stop_flag = ...` should have been `self.worker.stop_flag = ...` as it is changing the variable that is to be used in the worker class/thread. My mistake was assuming both classes inherited the same "self".

If there are other errors and or better explanations of what I did incorrectly, please do post an answer and I'll accept it!